# Find circles live with openCV and python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I am trying to find 2 circles in a field and mark them from the live data I am getting from the camera. The problem is that the houghCircles() function cannot always detect those circles even if their position is unchanged. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time 
wait = 5                                                                          
st = time.clock()  

on=0
arka=0
def circleS():
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_grs, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
              param1=150,
              param2=35,
              minRadius=5,
              maxRadius=30) 
    on=0
    arka=0


    if(circles[0,0,2]>circles[0,1,2]):
        on=(circles[0,0,0],circles[0,0,1])
        arka=(circles[0,1,0],circles[0,1,1])
    if(circles[0,0,2]<circles[0,1,2]):
        on=(circles[0,1,0],circles[0,1,1])
        arka=(circles[0,0,0],circles[0,0,1])
    cv2.circle(img_bgr,on,2,(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.circle(img_bgr,arka,2,(0,0,255),3)
    return on,arka

def takePic():
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    img_bgr = np.copy(frame)                                                         
    frame = None 
    return img_bgr

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1) 
while((time.clock()-st)<=wait):                                                
ret, frame = camera.read()                                                  # Capture a frame
    #cv2.imshow('Camera Stream',frame)                                           # Display the captured frame in a window named Camera Stream
    cv2.waitKey(1) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
while(1):    
    img_bgr=takePic()
    img_grs = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,img_bin = cv2.threshold(img_grs,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(img_bin,9,0.03,3)
    corners = np.int0(corners)
    on,arka=np.int0(circleS())
    for i in corners:
        x,y = i.ravel()
        if(x>=arka[0]+15 or x<=arka[0]-15 or y>=arka[1]+15 or y<=arka[1]-15 ):
             cv2.circle(img_grs,(x,y),3,255,-1)
    cv2.imshow("Camera Stream",img_bgr) 
    cv2.waitKey(10) 
    img_bgr = None
    img_grs= None
    time.sleep(5)


camera.release()
cv2.imshow("bin",img_bgr)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error I am getting is index out of bounds because of the circles array.  What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The index out-of-bounds error on circles is because the cv2.HoughCircles() may return an empty circles array when it does not find any circle (as you mention).

Put in an extra check after the cv2.HoughCircles() call:

```
if len(circles) > 0:
    # your circle stuff
```